# QuantLib: How to bootstrap Yield Curve using 3M futures

Tags: interpolation, bootstrapping, quantitative-finance, quantlib

I need to bootstrap a yieldcurve with 3M futures, using a cubic spline if possible.

Using, for example 3M Euribor, how do I bootstrap the yield curve using python?

I have a vector of dates and a vector of future prices.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The approach is general:

1. Decide on the parametrisation you are doing for your discount factors for example Z(0, T) = exp(-y(T) * T).
2. Suppose you have some market observables M_1, M_2, ..., M_n that are expiring in an increasing order T_1, T_2, ..., T_n, e.g. M_1 is the future expiring on T_1 = 1y, M_n is a swap expiring in T_n = 30y.
3. Assume y(T) is spline/constant function on [Ti, T_{i+1}] (assume some extra constraints if spline is used).
4. Write Price(M_i) = G_i(y(T_1), y(T_2), ..., y(T_i)), where G_i is a known formula (in this case the sum of the discounted coupons devided by the annuity) you see that the price of the observable M_i only depends on yields until T_i.
5. Use **bootstrapping** to find the y(T_i) i.e. Find y(T_1) such that Price(M_1) = G_1(y(T_1)) and once y(T_1) is found, find y(T_2) such that Price(M_2) = G_2(y(T_1), y(T_2)) while y(T_1) is fixed to the previous value and y(T_2) is the unknown. This way you can find all y(T_i).

**Some remarks:**

1. Futures are different that forwards, so you are likly to need a **convexity adjustment** to write the G_i.
2. Yields have **spikes** that you are not taking into accounts due to for example quarter fed meetings.
3. Your risk is **not localized** as you are using the spline, hence bumping the 10y swap for example will impact the 15y swap.
4. Day counts Fractions, Calendards and other convention are critical to take into account if in a prod environnement.
5. **You are assuming single curve** discounting/projection which is not necessarly the case, but could be the case if are futures on SOFR and discounting with SOFR. Or post Libor reform where the spread is constant.

Good luck.